# Skip tab in tablayout

Tags: android, tabs, android-tablayout, android-tabs

I need to skip particular tab. When user scroll from 1st to 2nd tab control should move to 3rd tab and vice versa.

I have override the OnTabSelectedListener for Tablayout and calling below function in tabselected method, but no result.

```
private class TabChangeListener implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        changeTab(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
}
```

Method to change tab.

```
private void changeTab(int pos) {
    if (pos == 1) {
        if (previousPos == 2) {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = mTabLayout.getTabAt(0);
            tab.select();
        } else if (previousPos == 0) {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = mTabLayout.getTabAt(2);
            tab.select();
        }
    } else
        previousPos = pos;
}
```

[The design i want to implement](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ud0lYeUxv-KasUDDF3gGacGuZX0elZER/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please show the error as well.

Comment: try `ViewPager.setCurrentItem(position)` instead of `tab.select()`

Comment: @SaurabhVadhva There is no errro. It's behave normally.. means 2nd tab is selecting

Comment: @SomeshKumarGurjar tried, but no use..